# Cannot access Grafana (Docker image) using port 3000 from non-local server

Tags: docker, ubuntu, tcp, grafana

I'm working on a Ubuntu server with Docker, in which I ran the Grafana Docker Image using the following commands (based on documentation: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/docker):

```
docker volume create grafana-storage
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name=grafana -v grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana grafana/grafana-oss
```

I can access to my Grafana instance successfully using localhost:3000, but the issue is that I cannot access from any external server `x.x.x.x:3000`. Not even locally unless I use `localhost`.

Nevertheless, I can access from an external server to `x.x.x.x` (port 80, which is being used by another process) from an external device.

I proceeded to check port configuration details:

`netstat -an | grep "3000"`

```
tcp        0      0 yy.yy.yy.yy:53596        yy.yy.yy.yy:3000        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 yy.yy.yy.yy:53716        yy.yy.yy.yy:3000        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 yy.yy.yy.yy:53700        yy.yy.yy.yy:3000        ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3000                ::1:50602               ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::1:50706               ::1:3000                ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3000                ::1:50706               ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 ::1:50602               ::1:3000                ESTABLISHED
```

`iptables -S | grep "3000"`

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 3000 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d yy.yy.yy.yy/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

`iptables -L INPUT -nvx`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 659 packets, 98721 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
     136     8160 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
       0        0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000
```

And noted that firewall was inactive, then I enable it and put a rule:
`sudo ufw enable`
`sudo ufw allow 3000/tcp comment 'grafana-port'`
`sudo ufw reload`
`sudo ufw status numbered`

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 3000/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # grafana-port
[ 2] 3000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # grafana-port
```

Applying this change did not make `x.x.x.x:3000` work. However, port 80 is still working normally as I mentioned. Maybe I am missing something else.

More info: I tried using `domain = x.x.x.x` and `serve_from_subpath = true` in `grafana.ini`, `defaults.ini` and `custom.ini` files. It did not work.

Have you any advice or contribution in order to solve this issue? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was solved letting the firewall inactive, and connecting to the server's router at [tplinkwifi.net](https://tplinkwifi.net). There I put this router configuration on `advanced > NAT forwarding > Port forwarding`:

```
Device IP Address: 192.168.x.x
External Port: 3000
Internal Port: 3000
Protocol: TCP
```

Then restarted the docker container and got access from non-local server.
Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
docker run -p x.x.x.x:3000:3000 ...
```

Comment: I have tried:
`docker run -p x.x.x.x:3000:3000 --name=grafana -v grafana-storage:/var/lib/grafana grafana/grafana-oss`
I got this:
`docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint grafana (c0fc637a193dbcd5b58154715835e8c73dd877383e846bc6f3a52a1ca9aa789d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp x.x.x.x:3000: bind: cannot assign requested address.
ERRO[0002] error waiting for container: context canceled`
Now I am researching about this error

Comment: Maybe port 3000 is already bound to something?